# Replacing an ETL framework with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, etl

Is there a successful implementation of replacing an ETL with traditional RDBMS with Cassandra ? Is there a way we can insert data into Cassandra simultaneously when we insert data into an Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and I saw similar solutions in practise. For Oracle there is [tungsten-replicator](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator), for MySQL there is an [open-replicator](https://github.com/whitesock/open-replicator) project (looks a bit abandoned) and a [MBCJ](https://github.com/shyiko/mysql-binlog-connector-java).

All these tools are requiring some manual work as they just act as a read-only replication slave, accepting all DB updates/deletes. And you have to write your own code to deal with actual row data.

I see this task in this way:

1. You create C* tables mirroring RDBMS schema as close as possible.
2. Tungsten/OR/MBCJ accepts a stream of RDBMS writes.
3. Your code transforms RDBMS row tuple to a form, compatible with cassandra DB schema.
4. Your code writes the data to C* cluster.

AFAIK Tungsten has some code related to [ETL via Apache Hadoop/Hive](http://docs.continuent.com/tungsten-replicator-3.0/deployment-hadoop.html), but it looks really scary: CSV files everywhere!